# Formato de hora: 12 vs. 24

Tags: ux, usabilidade

Qual formato de hora é mais legível para os usuários de *softwares* e *sites*?

- 13:00
- 1:00 PM

Comment: Não tem como responder essa pergunta sem levar para a questão de opiniões pessoais. Considero mais legível 13:00 em ambientes lusofonos, uma vez que PM não é tão típico na nossa lingua.

Comment: Eu diria que é um fator de usabilidade altamente baseado em cultura. Aqui nos Estados Unidos o formato 24:00 (chamado usualmente *Military Time* por razôes históricas) é considerado estranho, e muitas pessoas tem dificuldade em lê-lo.

Comment: Quem está votando pra reabrir podia expor seus motivos. Ao contrário do @Kyllopardiun não acho que PM seja algo estranho, e alguém do Paraná não pode falar por alguém do Maranhão...

Comment: Votei para reabrir. Embora concorde que a resposta certa é "depende", **isso** ainda é uma resposta, e objetiva IMHO. Afinal, quem desenvolve softwares/sites desenvolve pra alguém, e faz parte da disciplina de Usabilidade definir quem é esse alguém (brasileiros? portugueses? público global?) e com base nisso qual padrão utilizar - e quanto esforço gastar permitindo ao usuário customizar sua experiência. Alguns parâmetros nesse sentido seriam muito bem vindos.

Comment: Só de olhar, posso dizer que assimilo mais rápido o formato de 12 horas.

Comment: Concordo com o @mgibsonbr, e também votei para reabrir. Adicionalmente, acho que a tag mais apropriada pra essa pergunta é [tag:usabilidade] e não [tag:ux], pois a apresentação da hora envolve convenções sociais diretamente relacionadas à facilidade da compreensão da informação, e não alguma satisfação não pragmática.

Comment: Coloquei essa pergunta em discussão no Meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1720/discuss%C3%A3o-sobre-pergunta-suspensa-formato-de-exibi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-hora

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Sobre as Convenções

Antes de mais nada, é importante ressaltar que tanto os formatos de exibição das horas como a própria quantidade de horas em um dia completo (ou em períodos de noite e dia) são *convenções* estabelecidas*.

*<sup>A fonte principal das informações a seguir é o livro "Counting Time: A Brief History of the 24-Hour Clock", que é DRM-Free e pode ser [baixado gratuitamente de seu site](http://clock24.nfshost.com/counting-time.html).</sup>

Os Romanos (que herdaram essa convenção dos Egípcios e Babilônios) usavam o formato 12-horas porque mediam o período do dia separado do período da noite cada um com 12 partes, muito provavelmente devido a esse ser o número aproximado de ciclos da lua em um ano. Havia também a questão de que era simplesmente *mais fácil* representar dois períodos de 12 horas do que um único com mais intervalos, porque os números romanos acima de 12 eram menos familiares e consumiam mais espaço em dispositivos usados para medição do tempo (como um relógio, por exemplo). Ou seja, pode-se considerar que desde aquela época já existiam preocupações de usabilidade como a facilidade de compreensão e aprendizado, além de possivelmente alguma preocupação estética.

A contagem das horas do dia no formato 24-horas surgiu depois (durante a definição das *timezones*), por causa da ambiguidade de interpretação inata do formato 12-horas. Existe um "ditado" que diz que até mesmo um relógio parado está certo duas vezes por dia, que advém justamente dessa *ambiguidade de representação*. Claro que uma pessoa olhando o seu relógio analógico de pulso consegue inferir se a hora é pela manhã ou pela noite usando seu relógio biológico interno (isto é, comparando com quanto tempo faz que ela acordou) e também olhando pela janela, mas a ambiguidade era um grande problema na definição das tabelas horárias de partidas e chegadas de trens.

O formato textual de 12-horas tentava diminiuir essa ambiguidade com a adição das terminações "am" e "pm" (originados do latim "*ante meridiem*" e "*post meridiem*", ou seja, antes do meio dia e após o meio dia), mas ainda assim isso era difícil pra muitas pessoas. Imagine um bilhete de trem com a definição do horário de partida:

- 06:20am é claramente pela manhã, porque é as 6 horas antes do meio dia, e na prática as pessoas não gastam muito tempo considerando essa informação.
- Mas 12:00pm não é igualmente claro. Essa informação requer certo esforço cognitivo para considerar se 12:00pm é meio dia ou meia noite.

Aparentemente, no início dos transportes ferroviários muita gente perdeu viagens por dúvidas desse tipo, o que fez com que inicialmente companhias de transporte adotassem o formato 24-horas e eventualmente alguns países também. Além do livro citado acima, a [Wikipedia tem informações interessantes sobre as culturas que mais utilizam um ou outro formato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_by_country#Time).

### Sobre a Usabilidade e Experiência de Cada Escolha

Imagine um sistema qualquer que use a figura abaixo para representar o tempo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa figura é facilmente compreendida por qualquer ser humano como um relógio com horas (ponteiro pequeno) e minutos (ponteiro grande), pois trata-se de uma convenção utilizada há muitíssimo tempo na construção de dispositivos para medir e representar tempo. Entretanto, a ambiguidade descrita anteriormente é total *a não ser que a informação seja sobre a hora atual* (e apenas porque se considera que o utilizador da informação dependerá de outras informações externas para intuir o período do dia).

Por isso, apesar de ser uma metáfora amplamente conhecida (e ser por isso potencialmente útil para a usabilidade), ela dificulta o entendimento se a intenção for representar o início de um espetáculo ou sessão de cinema,  pois o utilizador simplesmente não vai entender a informação desejada (não sabendo quando o entretenimento começará).

A alternativa mais comum é utilizar um formato textual como os sugeridos na sua pergunta. Por exemplo, "06:20pm" (no formato 12-horas) ou "18:20" (no formato 24-horas) para exibir a mesma informação da imagem anterior. A melhor escolha depende fortemente da origem cultural do utilizador (critério de usabilidade relacionado às convenções sociais) e também de alguma preferência não pragmática (critério de experiência do usuário). Ainda assim, em contextos em que a ambiguidade precisa ser completamente removida, prefere-se utilizar o formato 24-horas:

> Na maioria das regiões em que se fala Inglês, particularmente nos
>   Estados Unidos, Filipinas e Reino Unido e suas antigas colônias, o
>   formato de 12-horas é predominante, usando-se o formato de 24-horas em
>   contextos em que a se deseja evitar a ambiguidade e ter acurácia no
>   acompanhamento do tempo, como no planejamento do transporte público.
>   ([Tradução livre da Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_by_country#Time))

É interessante notar que mesmo usando o formato 24-horas ainda pode haver ambiguidade em relação ao dia da semana em que certo evento ocorre. É comum*, por exemplo, que sessões de cinema ou teatro que comecem a meia noite tenham a hora de início marcada no bilhete como "23:59", isto é, usando o formato 24-horas e diminuindo 1 minuto do horário real para que fique *muito claro* para o utilizador tanto o horário de início como também o dia correto em que a sessão ocorrerá. Pode parecer bobagem, mas essa atitude é tomada simplesmente porque *é muito importante* para a experiência do utilizador que sejam evitados erros (segurança é outro critério de usabilidade importante).

*<sup>Digo isso principalmente com base na minha experiência pessoal como utilizador de entretenimento e transporte público no Brasil, Inglaterra e França.</sup>

### Norma de Representação Computacional

No caso da representação computacional (internamente, em relatórios ou na comunicação de dados de forma legível aos usuários), a [norma ISO 8601](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) estabelece o uso do formato 24-horas porque tem a intenção de que a *ordem cronológica seja a mesma que a ordem léxica* (por exemplo, no formato 12-horas uma listagem ordenada lexicamente faria com que a hora "05:00pm" seja listada incorretamente *antes* de "06:00am" - o que não ocorre  no formato 24-horas com "17:00" e "06:00" respectivamente).

### Concluindo

Não há uma resposta única para essa pergunta, porque o melhor formato irá depender do público alvo do sistema não somente em relação à sua origem cultural, mas também preferências pessoais, gênero e idade (crianças podem ter mais facilidade com o formato 12-horas, principalmente porque seu período de atividade é geralmente menor - provavelmente o dia, já que a noite elas devem dormir cedo, por exemplo). No caso de sistemas de uso bastante amplo (sistemas operacionais são o exemplo mais claro), é simplesmente mais fácil permitir a configuração do formato de exibição. Porém, quando se precisa evitar totalmente a ambiguidade, como no caso de agendamentos, parece ser mais seguro usar o formato 24-horas.

Comment: +1. Mas vale mencionar - 'Essa figura é facilmente compreendida por qualquer ser humano' [Citation Needed] Acredite, tem muita gente hoje em dia que não sabe 'ler' essa convenção.

Comment: Ótima resposta. Você só inverteu ali: o ponteiro pequeno é o das horas e o grande o dos minutos.

Comment: @OnoSendai Hahaha É verdade. Mas, ainda assim a metáfora é clara pra qualquer ser humano porque relógios analógicos existem até hoje em torres e praças, e por isso são amplamente utilizados (fora que as crianças aprendem a ler as horas com essa metáfora). É uma metáfora visual mais clara até do que o disquete usado no botão "Salvar" da maioria dos editores de texto. :)

Comment: @Andrey Oops! Valeu pelo aviso. :)

Answer (score 3):

Faltou especificar para onde é o software.
Baseando que a pergunta é em português e para finalizar essa questão.

Brasil e Portugual utilizam 24h ao invés de 12h.

**Logo a melhor opção é 13:00**

Comment: Provavelmente a lei "obriga" a usar o formato 24h em determinadas situações, então 24h é uma aposta melhor.