# Madrugada maior que noite

Tags: php

Como faço para identificar que

```
01:00:00(AM) é maior que 23:00:00h
```

Exite alguma função no php onde eu defina isso?

UPDATE:

```
if('2015-02-20 23:00:00' < '2015-02-21 01:00:00'){ //TRUE }
```

Comment: Como você esta tratando isso ? em que contexto isso aparece ?

Comment: em condições se a primeira hora 23 for > eu faco uma acao , de dia da certo, mas anoite sempre a primeira hora vai ser maior e vai executar a ação erroneamente, estu usando isso num sistema de ponto no case de quem trabalha de madrugada, mas tem que se aplicar nos 2 turnos

Comment: Acontece que `01:00:00(AM)` **não** é maior que `23:00:00h`. Todavia, `22/2/2015 01:00:00(AM)` é de fato maior que `21/2/2015 23:00:00h`. Ou seja, como disse @IsvaldoFernandes, falta você explicar o seu contexto.

Comment: Dependendo do caso, você pode simplesmente usar a data atual + horas extras para determinar isso.

Comment: Eu so preciso definir que 23:00:00 não é maior 01:00:00 da "madrugada"

Comment: Oi Rafael. O problema do "eu só preciso definir" é que como já foi bem explicado pelo @Caffé essa afirmação (1 da manhã *é maior* do que 11 da noite) vai ser verdadeira ou falsa dependendo do dia a que cada hora se refere. Por favor, edite a questão e forneça mais detalhes a respeito de como os dados são capturados e/ou mantidos, senão fica realmente difícil alguém te ajudar a descobrir o que você precisa.

Comment: Btw, pergunta levemente relacionada que também pode ser de alguma ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25594/formato-de-hora-12-vs-24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`01:00:00` não é maior que `23:00:00`.

No entando, para identificar se `21/02/2015 01:00:00` é maior que `20/02/2015 23:00:00` você pode comparar o timestamp. Por exemplo:

```
// mktime(hora, minuto, segundo, mes, dia, ano)
$timestamp1 = mktime(1, 0, 0, 2, 21, 2015);
$timestamp2 = mktime(23, 0, 0, 2, 20, 2015);

if ($timestamp1 > $timestamp2) {
    echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s", $timestamp1) . ' é maior que ' . date("d/m/Y H:i:s", $timestamp2);
    // 21/02/2015 01:00:00 é maior que 20/02/2015 23:00:00
}
```

Utilizei a função [`mktime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mktime.php) apenas como exemplo. Você pode utilizar qualquer recurso que retorne o timestamp ( [`time`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.time.php), [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php), ... ).

Comment: Boa resposta, só adicionaria um enfase na primeira linha, pois é justamente este o problema, "01:00:00 não é maior que 23:00:00" :) +1

Comment: So fiz essa verificação: if('2015-02-20 23:00:00' < '2015-02-21 01:00:00'){ //TRUE } deu certo o php entende isso é só adicionar a data, obrigado pelas dicas!