# Como ordenar horas

Tags: java

Eu possuo o seguinte método para ordenar um `ArrayList` de String de Horas:

```
 public static void ordenaHoras() {

        ArrayList<String> horasList = new ArrayList<String>();
        horasList.add("23:45");
        horasList.add("11:13");
        horasList.add("15:33");
        horasList.add("12:27");
        horasList.add("15:24");

        Collections.sort(horasList, new Comparator<String>() {

            private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                int result = -1;

                try {
                    result = sdf.parse(o1).compareTo(sdf.parse(o2));
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                return result;
            }
        });

        for (String hora: horasList) {
            System.out.println(hora);
        }
    }
```

O meu problema é que os valores de horas que comecem pelo numero 12 ficam indevidamente sempre em primeiro lugar!!! 
O output da execução do método de cima é:

```
12:27
11:13
15:24
15:33
23:45
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se as horas estão sempre no [formato 24h](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25594/73) e como strings, você não precisa convertê-las para comparar (isto é, usar o `SimpleDateFormat.parse`). Basta comparar em string mesmo. Ai vai ficar tudo na ordem desejada, sem dificuldade. :)

Agora, o problema é que pra você 12:27 é meio dia e vinte e sete, mas o sistema está considerando como meia noite e vinte e sete porque vc usou `hh` (minúsculo). Experimente usando `HH` (maiúsculo) na formatação. Conforme a [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> **H: Hour in day (0-23)**
>
> **h: Hour in am/pm (1-12)**